# webpack-dev-server and node-webkit

Tags: node.js, webpack, node-webkit, webpack-dev-server

Please tell me, is it possible to configure webpack-dev-server and node-webkit for development? I want to use nw modules and node modules for my application. If I build application (app.js, vendors.js, styles.css, index.html), then all is well, but but it is inconvenient for the development.
Thanks!